# Data Preprocessing in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to preprocess one of my columns in my Data frame. The issue is that I have [[ content1] , [content2], [content3]] in the **relations** column. I want to remove the Brackets

i have tried this following:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].str[0]
```

the output that i get is
[content 1]

```
df
print df

id     value                 
1      [[str1],[str2],[str3]]        
2      [[str4],[str5]]       
3      [[str1]]        
4      [[str8]]       
5      [[str9]]      
6      [[str4]]
```

the expected output should be like

```
id     value                 
1      str1,str2,str3        
2      str4,str5       
3      str1        
4      str8       
5      str9      
6      str4
```

Comment: Is the column all strings? Maybe `df['value'] = df['value'].str.replace(r'\[|\]', '', regex=True)`

Comment: i get NAN values

Comment: Please post a sample of your dataframe

Comment: It would be interesting to know the type of the values and the expected output

Comment: i have a sample Dataframe in the question

Comment: @xsrg45 [don't use images for data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Try `df['relations'].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(i[0] for i in x))`

Comment: @xsrg45, for future questions, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples to see how you can produce reprodible questions, including the structure of your data.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have lists of lists. You can try to unnest and join:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: ','.join([e for l in x for e in l]))
```

Or:

```
from itertools import chain
df['value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(chain.from_iterable(x)))
```

*NB. If you get an error, please provide it and the type of the column (`df.dtypes`)*

Comment: mozway, your first solution will yield like ` [,[,s,t,r,1,],,,[,s,t,r,2,],,,[,s,t,r,3,],]`

Comment: @KarnKunar My answer is on the basis that OP had lists of lists, not a string representation of lists (this the AttributeError) That said I could not test my code, I just wrote it done directly. Have you tested?

Comment: yes, based on the sample dataFrame provided by the OP, i've tested it and that's the output it generated. you could  see that as i reproduced in my answer ie list of lists only

Comment: OK, I had not seen this edit. Well, done things are ambiguous then. Let's wait and see. If this is really a string representation your answer should work ;)

Comment: OK, I had not seen this edit. Well, done things are ambiguous then. Let's wait and see. If this is really a string representation your answer should work ;)

Answer (score 0):

As I could see, your data and sampling the same:

### Sample Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'value':['[[str1],[str2],[str3]]', '[[str4],[str5]]', '[[str1]]',  '[[str8]]', '[[str9]]', '[[str4]]']})
print(df)
   id                   value
0   1  [[str1],[str2],[str3]]
1   2         [[str4],[str5]]
2   3                [[str1]]
3   4                [[str8]]
4   5                [[str9]]
5   6                [[str4]]
```

### Result:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].str.replace('[', '').astype(str).str.replace(']', '')
print(df)
   id           value
0   1  str1,str2,str3
1   2       str4,str5
2   3            str1
3   4            str8
4   5            str9
5   6            str4
```

**Note:** *as the error code says `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values` which means it's not treating it as `str` hence you may cast it to `str` by `astype(str)` and then do the replace operation.*

Comment: now i get this error for the both suggestions  AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: @xsrg45, please try , `df['value'].str.replace('[', '').astype(str).str.replace(']', '')` , i have edited my answer.

Comment: I bet that the brackets aren't part of the strings, but simply reflect that the cell contains a list of lists.

Comment: @coffeinjunky, what i could imagine from the error code is that its not treating it `str` while doing `replace`  hence we can try casting it first to `str` like `astype(str)` and then do the rest of the operation and that should do the Job, and it works as per sample provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use useful regex python package `re`.
This is the solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
```

**make the test data**

```
    data = [
        [1, '[[str1],[str2],[str3]]'], 
        [2, '[[str4],[str5]]'], 
        [3, '[[str1]]'], 
        [4, '[[str8]]'], 
        [5, '[[str9]]'], 
        [6, '[[str4]]']
    ]
```

**conver data to Dataframe**

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'value'])
    print(df)
```

[image]

**remove '[', ']' from the 'value' column**

```
    df['value']=df.apply(lambda x: re.sub("[\[\]]", "", x['value']),axis=1)
    print(df)
```

[image]